# Customize android spinner

Tags: android, customization, spinner

I am trying to customize spinner. I found this tutorial, http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57
It looks great but I am finding some errors all of which is like the following

```
 error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'state_dropdown_showing' in package 'android'
```

and the xml which leads to this error is

```
<!-- DROPDOWN SHOWING-->             
<item android:state_first="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_down"
      />    
<item android:state_middle="true" 
      android:state_dropdown_showing="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_up_down"
      />             
<item android:state_last="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="true"  
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_up"
      />   
<item android:state_single="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="true"  
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_neither_up_down"
      />                     

<!-- DROPDOWN NOT SHOWING-->

<item android:state_first="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="false" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_right_only"
      />    
<item android:state_middle="true" 
      android:state_dropdown_showing="false" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_left_right_collapsed"
      />             
<item android:state_last="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="false"  
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_left_only"
      />   
<item android:state_single="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="false"  
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_neither"
      />
```

And I am not finding anything in the net relevant to this. I am at a fix now. I want to change the look and feel of the regular spinner with nice color background.

Anybody please guide me about customization of spinner.

Comment: @Shaista: Have you made sure all of the button drawables are in the /res/drawable directory along with the xml file? Also make sure the names match (remember case-sensitivity and so on).

Comment: yes I have all set, if there were problem those they will get respective error. and when I remove android:state_dropdown_showing then there is no error. so the problem lies with android:state_dropdown_showing as the error also says the same thing :-(

Comment: @Shaista: I just tried this myself and I get exactly the same error. The strange thing is that the current Android docs for android.R.attr don't mention the state_dropdown_showing attribute although if you google for it, there are various references. I've even tried updating Eclipse to the latest ADT version and also all of the latest Android SDK stuff but it still isn't recognised.

Comment: yes MisterSquonk. You are right. I think I will have to take an alternative approach. I wonder y the tutorial is also not giving any hint about it and ofcourse  the SDK should have been updated atleast. But thanks, you made an effort for me.

Comment: @Shaista Naaz: Good luck, sorry I couldn't be of more help. I'll see if I can find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

android:state_dropdown_showing it is worked on after r15 version only..so update the android sdk tools version.it is hopefully helpful to all